# How to pass “values” attribute as array of strings in payload object in case of Googles AUTOML TABLE?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

We are  using Google cloud service AUTOML TABLES for online prediction.
We have created, trained and deployed the model. The model is giving predictions using the Google console. We are trying to integrate this model in our java code.
We are not able to pass “values”  attribute as array of strings in payload object in java code. We haven’t found anything for this in documentation.
Please find the links we are using for this:

- https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/samples/automl-tables-predict

Please find the json object in the screenshot.
**Please let us know how to pass “values”  attribute as array of strings in payload object**?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [reference](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/samples/automl-tables-predict) you are following, to be able to populate "values" you need to define it at the main(). You can refer to [Class Value.Builder](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Value.Builder.html) if you need to set Numbers, Null, etc. values.

```
List<Value> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("This is test data.").build()); 
// add more elements in values as needed
```

This list `values` will be used in `Row` that accepts iterable protobuf value. See [Row.newBuilder.addAllValues()](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-automl/latest/com/google/cloud/automl/v1beta1/Row.Builder.html#addAllValues-java.lang.Iterable-).

```
Row row = Row.newBuilder().addAllValues(values).build();
```

Using these, the payload is complete and a prediction request be built:

```
ExamplePayload payload = ExamplePayload.newBuilder().setRow(row).build();
PredictRequest request =
          PredictRequest.newBuilder()
              .setName(name.toString())
              .setPayload(payload)
              .putParams("feature_importance", "true")
              .build();

  PredictResponse response = client.predict(request);
```

Your full prediction code should look like this:

```
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.AnnotationPayload;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.ExamplePayload;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.ModelName;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictRequest;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictResponse;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.Row;
import com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.TablesAnnotation;
import com.google.protobuf.Value;
import com.google.protobuf.NullValue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class TablesPredict {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "your-project-id";
    String modelId = "TBL9999999999";
    // Values should match the input expected by your model.
    List<Value> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("blue-colar").build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("married").build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("primary").build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("no").build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("yes").build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("yes").build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("cellular").build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setNullValue(NullValue.NULL_VALUE).build());
    values.add(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("unknown").build());
    predict(projectId, modelId, values);
  }

  static void predict(String projectId, String modelId, List<Value> values) throws IOException {
    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (PredictionServiceClient client = PredictionServiceClient.create()) {
      // Get the full path of the model.
      ModelName name = ModelName.of(projectId, "us-central1", modelId);
    
      Row row = Row.newBuilder().addAllValues(values).build();
      ExamplePayload payload = ExamplePayload.newBuilder().setRow(row).build();

      // Feature importance gives you visibility into how the features in a specific prediction
      // request informed the resulting prediction. For more info, see:
      // https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/features#local
      PredictRequest request =
          PredictRequest.newBuilder()
              .setName(name.toString())
              .setPayload(payload)
              .putParams("feature_importance", "true")
              .build();
      PredictResponse response = client.predict(request);

      System.out.println("Prediction results:");
      for (AnnotationPayload annotationPayload : response.getPayloadList()) {
        TablesAnnotation tablesAnnotation = annotationPayload.getTables();
        System.out.format(
            "Classification label: %s%n", tablesAnnotation.getValue().getStringValue());
        System.out.format("Classification score: %.3f%n", tablesAnnotation.getScore());
        // Get features of top importance
        tablesAnnotation
            .getTablesModelColumnInfoList()
            .forEach(
                info ->
                    System.out.format(
                        "\tColumn: %s - Importance: %.2f%n",
                        info.getColumnDisplayName(), info.getFeatureImportance()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For testing purposes I used Google's test dataset (gs://cloud-ml-tables-data/bank-marketing.csv) and used the code above to run send prediction.

See test prediction:

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply Ricco D. 
Actually i have tried this before posting question.It didnt worked. Values attribute is going as object in payload not array of strings. Also getting below exception when i used the above code :- 
"java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
Values attribute is going as object and also in key and value format.

row {
  values {
    string_value: "This is test data."
  }
}